# Междометие "А"

Tags: междометие

Междометие, передающее множество оттенков настроения, но состоящее только из протяжного А, как должно быть обозначено?

Answer (score 1):

Как и все междометные предложения. Протяжность обозначается с помощью короткого тире:
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=130

§ 108. Междометные предложения имеют в конце восклицательный знак, многоточие (или сочетание знаков — восклицательного и многоточия):— А-а! — весело сказал старик (Шукш); — А-а-а... — сказал милиционер. — Значит, тоже любуетесь(Пауст.); А-а-а! Прочь отсюда, бегом (Т. Толст.)